# Run python script as non-root user

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-nifi

I installed python3 and required module with root access. But, When I try to run the scrip as non-root user. I am getting following error:

> No module found Error.

What is the right way to run the python3 script as non-root user. **virtualenv** works fine If interactively runs it. But, I need to run it from nifi. So, I should be able to execute it without virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to install the module as non-root, or more specifically, the user account that runs NiFi.

You shouldn't be using `sudo` with `pip` anyway

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to install Anaconda (big Python distribution with a nice installer) in a location accessible to NiFi and chown the Anaconda folder to the NiFi service account user.